# Where can I find each type of ultra rare cargo?

Tags: cargo-commander

I'm missing a lot of ultra rare cargo and it would be ideal to have a list of sectors where each type can be found. Of course, since the contents of each sector are procedurally generated based on its name, some cargo may be found in more than one sector; however, for the purposes of this answer, just one sector per cargo will do.

Answer (score 2):

List of sectors where each type of ultra rare cargo may be found:

- **vial of awesome:** 39916600
- **golden robot:** THISTLEDOWN
- **golden egg:** CTHULU
- **crystal skull:** BROKE
- **yellow green easter egg:** BUNNY
- **a friend:** APFELSTRUDEL
- **glow in the dark unicorn:** BLUPPLEBEE
- **lucky gnome:** HEADSUP
- **right sock:** OCTOBER
- **golden coffee mug:**  Sector18, LONELY
- **gram of unobtainium:** ORIGOI (notice no space)
- **bottle of serious brew:** SPACEAMERICA
- **golden alien head:** WOMBAT, MIMIGATOWN
- **hidden sweater:** TRUELOVE, RAVENHOLDM
- **epic bottle rocket:** PIZZA

Comment: I am creating a list of all cargo/sectors [here](http://catprog.org/Games/Cargo.html) Vial of Awesome is available in 39916600, A friend is APFELSTRUDEL, Crystal Skull is BROKE

Answer (score 0):

When you use a scanner on an item it will show you which sectors have it when you are browsing sectors in the navigator. For example I used a scanner on a pink flamingo, now when I'm looking at popular sectors to use my sector pass on any one that has a pink flamingo has a little icon that will pop up.

Comment: I know this, but sometimes I'll go through hundreds of sector names without ever finding one that has the cargo I'm looking for. For example, I haven't yet found a sector that has the "bottle of serious brew".

What I'm getting at is that I need a list of all the ultra rare cargo with the sectors where they may be found (I clarified the question accordingly). If such a list doesn't already exist, I might start it myself as community wiki later today.

Comment: @jSepia would be awesome